# Digit Sum Inequality: $a(n)\leq 9([\log a]+1)$

Tags: number-theory

Here: https://oeis.org/A007953 the identity
$$
a(n)\leq 9([\log_{10} n]+1)
$$
is given, where $a(n)$ is the digit sum.

I tried to use induction but I cannot get $\log_{10}(n+1)$ so I assume there has to be another way of proving it.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: looks like you are trying to prove...
$$a(n)\leq 9([\log n]+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

The log here is base $10$.  There are  at most $\log_{10}( a) + 1$ digits and each is at most $9$.